# I need to delete users from Active Directory using a imported csv file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a CSV file with a list of user names, I need to delete all of these users from Active Directory using the `Remove-ADObject command`.  I am not very familiar with the syntax for this command - hoping you guys can help me here.

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$list = Import-CSV C:\Users\user\Desktop\deleteuserstest.csv

forEach ($item in $list) {
    $samAccountName = $item.samAccountName
    Remove-ADobject -Identity $samAccountName
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the code does not work?

Comment: yes I am saying it does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use DN or GUID with Remove-ADObject. You can do something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$list = Import-CSV C:\Users\user\Desktop\deleteuserstest.csv

forEach ($item in $list) {
    $samAccountName = $item.samAccountName

    #Get DistinguishedName from SamAccountName
    $DN = Get-ADuser -Identity $Samaccountname -Properties DistinguishedName |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

    #Remove object using DN
    Remove-ADObject -Identity $DN
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  You are the best.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help! :) If this fixed your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: this is very useful and worked for me, but this code is prompting for confirmation for each user in the excel, since I've a requirement to delete thousands of accounts, is there any way i can skip this confirmation for each users ?

Comment: @JeganBaskaran if you add `-confirm:$false` to the end of the statement, that should do what you need. For example `Remove-ADObject -Identity $DN -Confirm:$false`

Comment: @Nick Thanks a lot for your help in replying .. that saved lot of my time. :)