# Remove-AdObject with Import-CSV error

Tags: powershell, active-directory, user-management

I am pretty green at Powershell and if this is simple, I apologize. I have tried to use this example script from user [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505430/i-need-to-delete-users-from-active-directory-using-a-imported-csv-file/44505567#44505567), and run into an error I thought AdObject was supposed to go around. My Script

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$list = Import-CSV C:\scripts\deletebulkusers.csv

forEach ($item in $list) {
    $samAccountName = $item.samAccountName

    #Get DistinguishedName from SamAccountName
    $DN = Get-ADuser -Identity $Samaccountname -Properties DistinguishedName |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

    #Remove object using DN
    Remove-ADObject -Identity $DN
}
```

I have posted my error below:

```
Remove-ADObject : The directory service can perform the requested operation only on a leaf object
At line:13 char:5
+     Remove-ADObject -Identity $DN -confirm:$false
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=<user>,DC=com:ADObject) [Remove-ADObject], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8213,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADObject
```

Comment: `-confirm:$false` looks syntactically wrong. `-confirm $false` looks better. If you remove this parameter completely, is it working fine?

Comment: If I remove it completely, I still have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad I could help :) I've had this happen to me before, specifically if the user has Outlook on their phone it turns them into a container. If you open Active Directory Users and Computers, select "View", and check the option for "View Users, Contacts, Groups and Computers as containers" the navigate to the object, you will see that there are items inside of it.

Using the `-recurse` parameter with `Remove-ADObject` is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Is there a risk that this will leave the mailbox orphaned and difficult to remove?

Comment: Not in my experience, although I can't say for certain. I've been running a script with this parameter daily for the past two years with no ill effects, however I'd imagine that may vary based upon the environment... it's only recursively removing ExchangeActiveSync devices in my environment.

Comment: The -Recursive cmdlet fixed my issue, along with @Mark-Wragg simplification of the script. Thanks so much to both of you!!

Comment: Also, with the -Recursive line, it marked the email accounts for deletion. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that the object you're trying to remove is a container. I suspect you may be proving the cmdlet the container of the object you want to remove rather than the object itself.

I think you can simplify the situation by using the pipeline:

```
Get-ADuser -Identity $Samaccountname | Remove-ADObject -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter if it looks like it's going to do what you expect.

Comment: I tried this, however I get the same error. I am only trying to delete a batch of users, all of them have email accounts, which I am assuming is where the issue is. The script will delete users without email, but not users with email.

Comment: It seems you need to disable their mailbox first. If you're using Exchange 2016 there's also `Remove-Mailbox` that will seemingly remove both mailbox and user account objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what my end script looked like. Both [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44806784/8226677) and [Mark Wragg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44806381/8226677)'s answers fixed my issue. Thanks guys!!

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$list = Import-CSV C:\scripts\deletebulkusers.csv

forEach ($item in $list) {
    $samAccountName = $item.samAccountName

    $DN = Get-ADuser -Identity $Samaccountname | Remove-ADObject -Recursive 
}
```